# DolphinDB: create a large matrix with repeat copies of matrix A

Tags: matrix, repeat, dolphindb

What should I do if I want to repeat copies of a matrix into a 2-by-2 block arrangement?

For example:

```
A=1..4$2:2

#0 #1
-- --
1  3 
2  4
```

I need to repeat it n times, the matrix should be

```
#0 #1 #2 #3
-- -- -- --
1  3  1  3 
2  4  2  4 
1  3  1  3 
2  4  2  4
```

Any idea how to accomplish this without using loop?

Answer (score 0):

Try the function`repmat`:

`repmat(A,2,2)`